# Is there any place where I can find test vectors for point addition and doubling of ECC?

Tags: elliptic-curves, test-vectors

I want to extensively test my implementation of point addition and doubling. I have only one test vector with me. I need more values to test.

In the web, I could find test vectors only for key pair generation and  signature verification. So if anybody can refer me a link containing test vectors, it will be of great help!

Thankyou.

Comment: You could check your implementation against existing, well-established tools like [sage](http://sagemath.org/).

Comment: @yyyyyyy         Can you share with me the exact page where test vectors are given in that site?. I couldnt find anything

Comment: yyyyyyy probably means that you should generate your own test vectors by executing those operations in sage.

Comment: @Arjtom B      Using sage to generate my own test vectors requires downloading the tool. Right now I'm not authorized to download tools as such

Comment: Just use random values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [Elliptic Curve Calculator](http://www.christelbach.com/ECCalculator.aspx).
It has point addition and scalar multiplication. For doubling, adding the same points(P+P) should do the work.